# Why does sssd break PTR records for AD-joined CentOS

Tags: centos, active-directory, kerberos, reverse-dns, sssd

I have an AD domain-joined CENTOS 7 box - call it `centosbox`.

Whenever SSSD starts, it updates the DNS records, which is fine by me, except that it breaks the PTR records by making them point to just `centosbox.` instead of `centosbox.my.domain.ext.`, which then breaks plenty of kerberos-related things, now that reverse DNS is broken.

Output of hostname on this box is:

```
#hostname -f
centosbox.my.domain.ext
```

How can I get it to register the correct value for the PTR records?

sssd.conf:

```
[sssd]
domains = my.domain.ext
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam, sudo

[domain/my.domain.ext]
ad_domain = my.domain.ext
krb5_realm = MY.DOMAIN.EXT
realmd_tags = joined-with-samba
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%d/%u
access_provider = ad
sudo_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldap://my.domain.ext
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/openssl/ca-bundle.trust.crt
ldap_group_search_base = DC=my,DC=domain,DC=ext    
ldap_sudo_search_base = OU=sudoers,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=ext
ldap_sasl_mech = GSSAPI
ldap_sasl_authid = CENTOSBOX$@MY.DOMAIN.EXT

[sudo]
```

krb5.conf:

```
includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

includedir /var/lib/sss/pubconf/krb5.include.d/
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = true
 dns_lookup_kdc = true
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = true
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

 default_realm = MY.DOMAIN.EXT
[realms]
 MY.DOMAIN.EXT = {
 }

[domain_realm]
 my.domain.ext = MY.DOMAIN.EXT
 .my.domain.ext = MY.DOMAIN.EXT
```

Additional info:

The sssd ldap_child.log file contains a ton of this:

```
(Mon Jun 18 21:01:40 2018) [[sssd[ldap_child[2245]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Client 'host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT' not found in Kerberos database
(Mon Jun 18 21:01:40 2018) [[sssd[ldap_child[2246]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Client 'host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT' not found in Kerberos database
(Mon Jun 18 21:01:40 2018) [[sssd[ldap_child[2247]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Client 'host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT' not found in Kerberos database
(Mon Jun 18 21:02:51 2018) [[sssd[ldap_child[2256]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Client 'host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT' not found in Kerberos database
(Mon Jun 18 21:02:51 2018) [[sssd[ldap_child[2257]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Client 'host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT' not found in Kerberos database
(Mon Jun 18 21:02:51 2018) [[sssd[ldap_child[2258]]]] [ldap_child_get_tgt_sync] (0x0010): Failed to init credentials: Client 'host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT' not found in Kerberos database
```

Ok, so that's blatantly false, because:

```
[root@centosbox sssd]#klist -ke
Keytab name: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
KVNO Principal
---- --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   4 centosbox$@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (arcfour-hmac)
   4 centosbox$@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 centosbox$@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (arcfour-hmac)
   4 host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 host/centosbox.my.domain.ext@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 host/centosbox@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (arcfour-hmac)
   4 host/centosbox@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
   4 host/centosbox@MY.DOMAIN.EXT (aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96)
```

What's the deal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are suffering from the redhat recommendation to require FQDN set hostname: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/ch-configure_host_names

SSSD seem to require a FQDN to be returned from hostname function without the -f flag.

Here is a similar question
https://lists.fedorahosted.org/archives/list/sssd-users@lists.fedorahosted.org/thread/QHBRCO2JR36PT5F4ZPZNGUHCEE5E4G42/